# Replicas: Synchronize changes for individual feature class (not entire replica)

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, replication

I have two ArcSDE databases, running with a two-way replica.One serves our interactive mapping website which gives certain users the ability to update, add points, edit attributes, etc. Then we have our master which is updated frequently by power users.

There are only a few feature classes that are currently being edited, and  I would like to synchronize these updates ONLY if these feature classes have been edited.

I've developed a python script using the compare features tool, which compares the feature datasets with the master. I'd like to only synchronize changes from these three layers, update the master (so child to parent) and then have the master sync any new changes to the edit database (parent to child).

Is there any way to synchronize changes and schema for individual datasets or is there a better way to go about this?

```
import arcpy    
aburg_master_DBO_TownOwnedJan2013 = "Database Connections\\Connection to       gisserver.sde\\aburg_master.DBO.Geocortex\\aburg_master.DBO.TownOwnedJan2013"
Aburg_Edit_DBO_TownOwnedJan2013 = "Database Connections\\Connection to gisserver(2).sde\\Aburg_Edit.DBO.Geocortex\\Aburg_Edit.DBO.TownOwnedJan2013"
compare_txt = "C:\\Test\\compare6.txt"

# Process: Feature Compare
result = arcpy.FeatureCompare_management(aburg_master_DBO_TownOwnedJan2013,   Aburg_Edit_DBO_TownOwnedJan2013, "GlobalID", "ATTRIBUTES_ONLY", "IGNORE_M;IGNORE_Z", "0.001 Unknown", "0", "0", "", "OBJECTID;created_user;created_date;last_edited_user;last_edited_date", "NO_CONTINUE_COMPARE", compare_txt)
changes = result.getOutput(1)
print "Comparision Result is: " + changes
change = str(changes)
if change == 'false':
    print "LOL"
else:
    print "Nope"
```

Comment: I'm glad to see I'm not the only person that uses lol in my scripts....

Comment: Essentially a replica can be any single data set or even version. You set up the replica in a map document.

Comment: the quick & dirty way is to create replicas for individual datasets when you need it, there's no problem to use multiple replicas.

Comment: I suppose I could create multiple replicas... I would like to hear other options though, as each time I create a replica I have to turn off our services and each replica takes 20 + mins to run

Comment: Why do you have to turn off your services? I'm surprised by that. We have a very similar circumstance to yours and our replicas sync everyday via script. I'm curious to see how you handle the automation of schema changes...something I've wanted to script for some time now, but haven't gotten around to it. Oh, and as other users said, no problem running multiple replicas on the same GDB.

Comment: @Clickinaway It seems that when I leave the services running it causes error logs on our server and messes with the services - I will try and verify this again. 
I'm trying to create another replica for those featureclasses but so far it keeps failing because "the same path name already exists" ... I've deleted the featureclasses from the "child" so I'm a bit confused....  
As for the schema changes  I'll have to get back to you - I had it working for a one-way replica but two-way is confusing!

Comment: If the data already exists, I think you want to register existing data instead.